# Excel VBA format numbers to specific value in UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have UserForm that dispalys values out of cells on my sheet "Price calculations". First column A on sheet "Price calculation" has text in rows from 72 to 88. All the rest of the columns D, E, F, G, H... etc has numbers I want to format.

I want to format cells to specific format for values with 17 rows `k=17` (columns D, E, F, G, H... etc) is my code. I want to use format `Format(XXX.Value, "#,##0.00")` so my numbers will look like 71 000,00 instead of 71000

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim vDB As Variant, a As Variant, c As Variant
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price calculation")

a = Array("a", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n") 'column characters
c = Array(409, 444, 480, 516, 552, 588, 624, 660, 696, 732, 768, 804) 'label numbers

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    If i = 0 Then
        k = 16
    Else
        k = 17
    End If
    vDB = Ws.Range(a(i) & 72).Resize(k)
    n = 0
    For j = c(i) To c(i) + k - 1
        n = n + 1
        Me.Controls("Label" & j).Caption = vDB(n, 1)
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: And what's stopping you?

Comment: Lack of knowledge I guess

Comment: Set `vDB` as the range of cells and not an array I guess.  After you've _set_ it just give it the required `NumberFormat`:    `vdb.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"`.

Comment: Ha, good answer. I asked because you seem familiar with Format. But not sure what you are doing anyway. Are you trying to format elements of an array?

Comment: If you want to format on your labels you are probably looking for: `Me.Controls("Label" & j).Caption = Format$(vDB(n, 1), "#,##0.00")`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - think that is only the property of a range?

Comment: @SJR Yes, it's the property of the range but the OP said _I want to format cells_ so I went with that.  I was going to suggest using more meaningful variable names so the code is easier to read - I kinda stopped reading when everything turned into `i`, `k`, `n` and `j`.  `Me.Controls("Label" & j).Caption = vDB(n, 1)` is a form label though so maybe I should've read further. :)

Comment: That seems to derive from a particular school of programming. Not sure any of us are entirely clear what is being asked here.

Comment: I have edited my post. Maybe my problem is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("D72:N88").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

to format the cells D72:N88 in worksheet `YourSheetName`.

Or

```
Me.Controls("Label" & j).Caption = Format$(vDB(n, 1), "#,##0.00")
```

If you want to format on your labels.

Comment: `Format$(vDB(n, 1), "#,##0.00")` - it is actually this one. I didn't know you have to insert $ after Format O_o

Comment: @user7202022 The issue was that you asked to *"format cells"* but you actually wanted to format the *"labels"*. You should be clear with the terms you use! • Actually the only difference is that `Format$()` returns a `String` while `Format()` returns a `Variant`. Both should work but `Format$()` is a little faster in this case.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I have to improve my English language skills as well. A lot to improve tho